# On a Day Like Today program

Tags: php, arrays, date, date-comparison

I have made a program that finds the current date and then do a search in a php array and shows what happens On a Day Like Today. The only problem is that the program can't read the months 10-12 correctly. Here is my code:

The php array:

```
$anniversary = array(
   '1/01' => array (
       '1813' => 'something here',
       '1824' => 'something here',
       '2001' => 'something here'
    ),
    '31/12' => array(
       '-450' => 'something here',
       '-168' => 'something here',
       '1942' => 'something here'
    )
);
```

And the program is:

```
<?php
include 'array.php';
$today = date('d/m');

foreach ($anniversary[$today] as $hdate => $event) {
    $table[0][] = $hdate;
    $table[0][] = $event;
    $counter++;
}

do {
    $random = rand(0, $counter * 3);
} while($random % 2 == 0);

echo '<h2>'.$table[0][$random-1].": ".'</h2>'.
     '<p>'.$table[0][$random].'</p>';
?>
```

The Problem is that the months 01-09 finds out and shows correctly and the months 10-12 can't finds because confuse the month with the day.
Any solutions?

Comment: `d` is "days with leading zeroes" - why you use `'1/01'` instead of `'01/01'`?

Comment: Also, why don’t you just use another array-level for separation of month and day? So `$anniversary[month][day][year]` or something?

Comment: Fixed your indentation for you.

Comment: Always use timestamps or any other normalized format when working with date / times. There will be no more confusion, and you will have plenty of built-in php function to work with this format. Don't reinvent the square wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing's getting "confused" but you. :)

In fact the problem is not months, but days. Your array's date format is `j/m` (no leading zeroes on date, no leading zeroes on month), but you're doing lookup with `d/m` (leading zeroes on date, no leading zeroes on month).

[When I fix your date format, the program works well.](http://codepad.org/70DTDToa)